# Advantages of 'pointer to a function' when using design patterns

Tags: c++, design-patterns, pointers

In C++ we can make pointers to functions. So that we can pass a 'pointer to a function' as an argument to another function. When we consider about design patterns, are there any specific design patterns which specially take the advantage of using 'pointer to a function'?

Answer (score 8):

Any design pattern that makes use of callbacks; such as visitor, strategy, and observer. Note that in C++, functors are also available to you and are generally preferred by the STL.

Answer (score 2):

Most anything you can achieve with a pointer to a function, you can achieve with a functor with better optimization, or with virtual methods for better OO design. However, a pointer to a function is a requirement for narrow use cases where C code and C++ code are interfacing with each other. An OO design pattern can still allow C code to participate in the pattern. And, certain C interfaces only accept function pointers, so C++ code that use those APIs have to pass one in.

A function pointer is generally used as a means to call some code that is registered in some kind of subscription/publish model (event notification). For example, it could be used for the `handle()` method in the *state pattern*.

But, it can also be used as a simple hook to get code to run within a particular framework. For example, `pthread_create` takes a function pointer that is to be called after a thread is launched.

Answer (score 1):

I generally see this done when a certain part of a function needs to be customized for certain cases. Allowing for the same function to take on multiple uses, this is demonstrated in the for_each function of C++, which goes through an iterable and applies a function to it. It really just allows for more reusable code.

On a related note, the C++ standard library uses a similar setup for it's container classes.

For example:

```
template < class T, class Container = deque<T> > class stack;
```

is the decleration for the stack class. As you can see, it takes in a configurable parameter for what it's underlying data structure is, this is similar to how a function pointer could be used.

EDIT: or the mentioned callbacks from other posters.